# List all Articles on a page Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I am new to Drupal. I've created different articles and now I want to show them on one of my pages (Let's say the "Articles" page). How do I do this? Some other sites suggest to use "views" for this, but isn't there a more easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

Views is a good way to show your "articles", but it's recommended to spend time learning and understanding the view module so you can customize it as you like.

You can also get your content programmatically, here is a quick example how to load all nodes of a content type :

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','your_custom_type')->execute();
$nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

PS: I really recommend you to learn the views module before using it, else you will find a problem when you need to add more functionalities.